# Hooking to a program structure safely with std::atomic<int> for threaded access?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, c++11, shared-memory

I'm wondering if it's possible to use "atomic access" (C++11 feature) for multi threaded acces from within a DLL injected into another process.

For example, we have this program:

```
struct SSomeStructure
{
    int value_a;
    int value_b;
};

int main()
{
    SSomeStructure some_variable;
    while(!GetAsyncKeyState('Q'))//loop while Q is not pressed
    {
        std::cout << some_variable.value_a << some_variable.value_b;
        some_variable.value_a = GetTickCount();
        some_variable.value_b = -some_variable.value_a;
        std::cout << some_variable.value_a << some_variable.value_b;
    }
}
```

And the program is closed source, but I have disasemlbed the "SSomeStructure" structure:

```
struct SSomeStructure
{
    int value_a;
    int value_b;
};
```

Now I am writing a DLL which is going to be injected into the process, but there is nothing to hook to except std::out, so, without hooking but making another thread, to safely access/modify those variables, they would need to be atomic, right?

So I was thinking to create this in my (pseudocode) DLL:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

//disasembled structure, but added syd::atomic
struct SSomeStructure
{
    std::atomic<int> value_a;
    std::atomic<int> value_b;
};

//start thread when dll loads etc...

void SomeThread()
{
    SSomeStructure * some_variable = ObtainAddressOfSomeVariableFromHostProcess();
    while(true)
    {
        some_variable->value_a = 1337;//is this now an atomic operation which is thread-safe?
    }
}
```

Would the std::atomic in my "hack" dll which runs it's own thread, give safe multi-threaded access to global variables in the host process? (because the DLL is accessing the value atomicly in the host process?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, this program exhibits undefined behavior; you are accessing an object of one type through a pointer to another, unrelated type.

It won't work in practice either. It takes two to tango: for two threads to observe a consistent state of a scalar object, **both** threads must use atomic instructions to access and modify it. Think about it this way: you may take a lock before you increment a counter, but it won't do you any good if another thread increments said counter without first taking the same lock.

In the limit, the host process might have loaded the value of `some_variable->value_a` into a register and is not observing any of your modifications at all.